# Looking for an alarm / errors console

Tags: python

The software which we have written for our IoT fleet is generating errors and alarms and I want to send these to a central location where I can see and manage them. I have looked for something like this but only found Nagios. For one thing, Nagios is for remote *monitoring* via *probes*, not collecting alarms; for another, I have used Nagios from time to time and really hope to avoid it this time.

Is there something out there that I have missed?

Thanks!

Comment: So,u want to capture these errors and alarms,U can use the tool Sentry(https://sentry.io)